# Using linq with PropertyValueCollection

Tags: linq

I'd like to know if there is a way or more efficient way using Linq.  Instead of using the while loop, is it possible to do a select where using **Linq query**?

```
  public UserPrincipal GetUser(string sUserName, string spwd, string domain, string ou)
    {
        PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, ou, sUserName, spwd);


        UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);

        DirectoryEntry user = (DirectoryEntry)oUserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
        PropertyCollection pc = user.Properties;
        IDictionaryEnumerator ide = pc.GetEnumerator();

        ide.Reset();

        while (ide.MoveNext())
        {
            PropertyValueCollection pvc = ide.Entry.Value as PropertyValueCollection;
            if (ide.Entry.Key.ToString() == "XYZ")
            {
                //Response.Write(string.Format("name: {0}", ide.Entry.Key.ToString()));
                //Response.Write(string.Format("Value: {0}", pvc.Value));

            }

        }
    .......;
    .......;


    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't use `Where()` on a `PropertyCollection` is because it implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, when `Where()` is a method of only the generic version.  You can convert a `PropertyCollection` to a generic `IEnumerable` by using [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

```
var matches = pc.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Where(p => p.Key.ToString() == "XYZ");

foreach( var match in matches )
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("name: {0}", match.Key));
    Response.Write(string.Format("Value: {0}", match.Value));
}
```

This way is doubtfully any more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        foreach (PropertyValueCollection pvc in pc.OfType<PropertyValueCollection>().Where(v => v.PropertyName == "XYZ"))
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("name: {0}", pvc.PropertyName));
            Response.Write(string.Format("Value: {0}", pvc.Value));
        }
```

Besides, you can try to use `ForEach`:

```
        pc.OfType<PropertyValueCollection>()
          .Where(v => v.PropertyName == "XYZ")
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(pvc =>
          {
              Response.Write(string.Format("name: {0}", pvc.PropertyName));
              Response.Write(string.Format("Value: {0}", pvc.Value));
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old thread, but I was searching for a way to work with PropertyCollection using LINQ.  I tried the suggested methods, but I always get an invalid cast exception when casting to DictionaryEntry.  And with a DictionaryEntry, things like FirstOrDefault are funky.  So, I simply do this:

```
var directoryEntry = adUser.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
directoryEntry.RefreshCache();
var propNames = directoryEntry.Properties.PropertyNames.Cast<string>();
var props = propNames
    .Select(x => new { Key = x, Value = directoryEntry.Properties[x].Value.ToString() })
    .ToList();
```

With that in place, I can then easily query for any property directly by Key.  Using the coalesce and safe navigation operators allows for defaulting to an empty string or whatever..

```
var myProp = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "someKey"))?.Value ?? string.Empty;
```

Note that the "adUser" object is the UserPrincipal object.